# Grails: Load jdbcDriver in Controller

Tags: grails, jdbc, grails-orm

I have to create a new SQL-Connection in a controller.
So I created a new controller and its action where I do

```
def db = [url:'jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB', user:'sa', password:'', driver:'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver']
def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
```

But I do get:

```
Class: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Message: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

Importing fails and I can't find information about this in documentation. Can you help? 
Thank you.

Comment: Did you add the hsqldb driver to your dependencies / classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the hsqldb Driver is in the dependencies list in `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`

```
 dependencies {

    //other dependencies
    //...

    runtime group: 'org.hsqldb', name: 'hsqldb', version: '2.3.1'
 }
```